# Is it possible for ktlint to find unwanted functions in code?

Tags: kotlin

I want [ktlint](https://ktlint.github.io/) to find unwanted functions (like `print`, `println`, `printStackTrace()` and etc.) in my code and give me warnings. Is it possible to setup such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible neither with [ktlint's standard rules](https://github.com/shyiko/ktlint#standard-rules) nor with EditorConfig (also respected by ktlint).

You can, however, [create your own ruleset](https://github.com/shyiko/ktlint#creating-a-ruleset) with rules for disallowing listed functions.